# Connecting multiple outlets to single action?

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, iboutlet, custom-keyboard

I'm creating a keyboard extension in XCode Beta 7 (Swift2).

I'm trying to connect multiple buttons to a single action.

However, when I connect all the button outlets to this action, it causes my keyboard to crash which makes me think there's something I'm missing.

```
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UIButton!


@IBAction func ButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    Label.setTitle("Hello!", forState: .Normal)
    Label.hidden = false
    Label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "hideLabel", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func hideLabel() {
    Label.hidden = true
    Label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Attaching the same action to multiple buttons is not a problem, and is a common technique.

However, you have Label set as force-unwrapped, which will crash if it is nil.

My guess is that your Label outlet is not connected so Label is nil at runtime.

Change the type of Label from `UIButton!` to `UIButton?` and then change your code to use "if let" optional binding to only execute the code using Label if label is non-nil.

BTW, Swift has a strong naming convention. Variable names should start with a lower-case letter and use "camel case" for the rest of the variable name. Only class names and type names should start with a capital letter. So "Label" should be "label" instead. Get in the habit of following that style. It serves as a clear visual cue to you and others reading your code as to what type of thing a name refers to.

Finally, "Label" is a horrible name for a button. It's a button, not a UILabel. Call it "myButton" or something instead.

### EDIT

The code might look like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton?


@IBAction func ButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) 
{
  println("myButton = \(myButton)")  //See if myButton is nil
  if let myButton = myButton
  {
    myButton.setTitle("Hello!", forState: .Normal)
    myButton.hidden = false
    myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, 
      selector: "hidemyButton", 
      userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

@objc func hidemyButton() 
{
    myButton.hidden = true
    myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me a little more information on what "change your code to use "if let" optional binding to only execute the code using Label if label is non-nil." looks like? Like I said, I'm such a noob at this and still learning the basics. :) Thank you again!!!

Comment: I just edited my post to provide example code. I took pity on you because you're new. Normally we frown on "show me the code" type questions, and ask you to do your own research first.

Comment: Thank you -- forgive me, I'll keep that in mind for the future. However, after implementing the code and connecting the outlets, the keyboard is still crashing whenever I click on a button.

Comment: So post the specifics of your crash. Which line is crashing. What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error codes, but when I build the app and simulate on my IOS device, the keyboard crashes whenever I click on the button associated with "ButtonTapped".

Comment: You must be getting a message when you crash. You're making it impossible to get enough information to help you. I give up.

Comment: I'm sorry to confuse you, I'm not sure how else I can explain this -- the app builds fine, but when I simulate on my IOS device, open the iMessage app, navigate to the custom keyboard I've built, and click on a button (the button associated with the "ButtonTapped" action in the coding), the keyboard goes blank then skips to the Apple IOS keyboard.